# android external storage permission on API 22

Tags: java, android, permissions

Hi so I have created an app that uses camera to capture image and saves that on the sd card and reads that.

I have tested that on my tablet which is rooted using `android 4.4` and it worked fine. but when I try to test it on my rooted phone (`android 5.1.1`) it gives me that error:

```
pkg: /data/local/tmp/*******
Error: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 2000 nor current process has android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES.
```

I have inserted the permission code on the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

any idea what causing that?
why is it working on 4.4 but not on 5.1.1?

thanks.

Comment: The message you quote has nothing to do with your issue.  Look further in logcat for something relevant.

Comment: try this `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />` in your manifest. update if that works.